# Full Calender not allow to Create continuous event

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am using fullCalendar with `initialView: 'resourceTimeline',` and I am faching some issues:

Date **22/03/2022** has two events 12 am to 5 am **and** 5 am to 9 am -> this is not allowing me to add continuously
Date **23/03/2022** has two event: 12 am to 5 am **and** 5.15 am to 9 am -> this is successfully added

Screenshot of the issue:
[image]

On **22/03/2022** when I create the first event to start selecting in calender time **12am to 5am** it will create properly. But after that I try to create the second event from **5 am to 9 am**, it is not allowing it as the "block" icon is appearing automatically (you can see in the screenshot).

But it is allowing me to select from **5.15 am**.

So my question is why it is not allowing me to create a second continuous event? 12 am to 5 am event is ok but after then 5 am to 9 I am not allowed.

I have set the following calendar options:

```
calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
  plugins: [interactionPlugin, resourceTimelinePlugin],
  resourceAreaColumns: [ {  field: 'title', headerContent: 'Date' }],
  resources: this.makeResourceData(),
  resourceOrder: 'orderVal',
  events: this.events,
  initialView: 'resourceTimeline',
  selectable: true,
  editable: false,
  eventResizableFromStart: true,
  eventOverlap: false,
  selectOverlap: false,
  slotDuration: '00:15:00',
  height: 'calc(100vh - 181px)',
  resourceAreaWidth: '150px',
  slotMinWidth:1,
  eventDurationEditable: false, // Disable Resize
  eventStartEditable: false, // disable dreage drop
  eventTimeFormat: {
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    hour12: true
  },
  headerToolbar: false,
  dayHeaderFormat: { weekday: 'short', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' },
  eventDidMount: this.renderPopHover.bind(this), // call before click event
  eventClick: (arg: EventClickArg) => this.selectEvent(arg),
  select: (arg: DateSelectArg) => this.addEvent(arg),
}


// load at first time with Old Schedules
arrangeSchedules(objSheduleData) {
this.generateEventId = 0;
this.events = [];
objSheduleData.forEach(element => {
    if (element.scheduleDetails && element.scheduleDetails.length > 0) {
        element.scheduleDetails.forEach(element12 => {
            const startDate = new Date();
            startDate.setSeconds(0);
            startDate.setHours(element12.startTime.hour);
            startDate.setMinutes(element12.startTime.miniute);
            const endDate = new Date();
            endDate.setSeconds(0);
            endDate.setHours(element12.endTime.hour);
            endDate.setMinutes(element12.endTime.miniute);
            let timeText = this.datePipe.transform(startDate, 'hh:mm a')
            timeText = timeText + ' - ' + this.datePipe.transform(endDate, 'hh:mm a')
            this.events.push({
                eventId: this.generateEventId + 1,
                resourceId: new Date(element.date).toDateString(),
                date: new Date(element.date),
                title: timeText,
                start: startDate,
                end: endDate,
                textColor: 'white',
                backgroundColor: '#0D7257',
                doctorScheduleDisplayType: element12.doctorScheduleDisplayType,
                locationId: element12.locationId,
                isOverbookingAllow: element12.isOverbookingAllow,
                overBookingLimit: element12.overBookingLimit,
                frequency: element12.frequency,
                id: element.id
            });
            this.generateEventId = this.generateEventId + 1;
        });
    }
});
this.loadEvents(this.events);
}

addEvent($event) {
if (this.isManagingInOldDate($event)) {
    this.notificationService.openError(this.translateService.instant('Can_CTtCreateOldDateSchedule'));
} else {
    this.selectedEventArray = [];
    this.deleteButtonVisible = false;
    if (this.events.length === 0) {
        this.generateEventId = 0;
    }
    const oldDate = new Date($event.resource._resource.id);
    const resourceId = oldDate.toDateString();
    this.generateEventId = this.generateEventId + 1;
    const addNewEvents = this.events;
    let timeText = this.datePipe.transform($event.start, 'hh:mm a')
    timeText = timeText + ' - ' + this.datePipe.transform($event.end, 'hh:mm a')

    const event = {
        eventId: this.generateEventId,
        title: timeText,
        resourceId: resourceId,
        start: $event.start,
        backgroundColor: '#5782FA',
        end: $event.end,
        textColor: 'white',
    };
    addNewEvents.push(event);
    this.selectedEventArray.push(event);
    this.loadEvents(addNewEvents);
}
}

loadEvents(finalEvents) {
let calendarApi;
if (this.calendarComponent) {
    calendarApi = this.calendarComponent.getApi();
}
this.events = [];
for (const event of finalEvents) {
    this.events.push(event);
}
if (calendarApi) {
    calendarApi.setOption('events', this.events);
}
}
```

Comment: I can't directly reproduce this with the information provided - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/rNpMdzO . I suspect we need to see what you're doing in the `addEvent` function. Please edit the question to include it.

Comment: P.S. Why are you using resources to represent dates? That's not how FullCalendar works. The timeline already deals with dates. Any events you create in fullCalendar must be given a specific start date. If you then view a different date in the timeline the event wouldn't shown any more, regardless of which resource it's associated with. Maybe you've found a workaround for that but it's a mis-use of how the calendar is supposed to operate, and limits its capabilities.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for replay and question update, i updated some code in Question. please see it

Comment: P.S. Why are you using resources to...
@ADyson its our Requirement that we need to show events date wise time wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need To set Milli seconds also and it Working

```
startDate.setMilliseconds(0);
endDate.setMilliseconds(0);
```